# Convert distance between 2 points in a plane into distance between two point on Earth

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

So finding the distance between two points in a plane and between two points on Earth is a pretty easy google search away, but converting one to the other I couldn't find how to do.

Using these two functions

```
function dist = (lat1: number, lng1: number, lat2: number, lng2: number) => {
    return Math.sqrt((lat1 - lat2) * (lat1 - lat2) + (lng1 - lng2) * (lng1 - lng2))
}

function distOnEarthInMeters = (lat1: number, lng1: number, lat2: number, lng2: number) => {
    if (lat1 === lat2 && lng1 === lng2) return 0

    const radianLat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180)
    const radianLng1 = lng1 * (Math.PI / 180)
    const radianLat2 = lat2 * (Math.PI / 180)
    const radianLng2 = lng2 * (Math.PI / 180)
    const earthRadius = 6378137
    const diffLat = radianLat1 - radianLat2
    const diffLng = radianLng1 - radianLng2
    const sinLat = Math.sin(diffLat / 2)
    const sinLng = Math.sin(diffLng / 2)
    const a = Math.pow(sinLat, 2.0) + Math.cos(radianLat1) * Math.cos(radianLat2) * Math.pow(sinLng, 2.0)
    return Math.floor(earthRadius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt(a))))
}
```

I get these:

```
dist(-27, -42, -26, -41) === 1.4142135623730951
distOnEarthInMeters(-27, -42, -26, -41) === 149386
```

But can can I turn one into the other without knowing the coordinates?

make `1.4142135623730951` become `149386` and `1.4142135623730951` become `149386`

(copied to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489148)

Comment: This is a geometry problem, not programming. Try asking in [math.se]

Comment: This will depend on the projection used. For example on the common Mercator Projection a distance in one part of the map will not equal a distance on another because size changes with latitude.

Comment: Your first function's input parameters expect x and y values as actual distances while the second function works with two angular coordinates (latitude: -90°...90° and longitude: -180°...180°). So you are not comparing like with like here.

Comment: The first function `dist` is wrong. A factor of `cos(lat)` on `lng` is required.

Answer (score 1):

As others said this is a math problem. But the answer is no you can't find it. Every map projection changes some distances on the globe. Some projections can conserve some distances, but never all.

Comment: interesting, but knowing that these specific functions were used, it should be possible right?

Comment: @LucasSteffen You can't transform one distance in one to  a distance in the other without knowing the locations of the points. The idea is that you can't transform the globe into a flat surface without stretching some areas different from others. When you stretch some areas different from others some distances are stretched differently from others. In this example you are comparing distances on an equirectangular map to distances on the  globe. If you look on  the wikipedia page for equrectangular projection the second image gives an idea on the stretching. Distances are stretched differently.